# MySQL - SELECT data where JSON key-pair value is something

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select, syntax

I'm trying to construct a MySQL query that would do the following:

Sample Data:

```
---------------------------------------------
|                  colm                     |
---------------------------------------------
|{"level":10, "something": "blah", etc}     |
---------------------------------------------
|{"level":3, "something": "blah", etc}     |
---------------------------------------------
|{"level":7, "something": "blah", etc}     |
---------------------------------------------
|{"level":21, "something": "blah", etc}     |
```

I need to `SELECT` rows where `colm LIKE "%?%"` with the `?` being level is less than or equal to (`<=`) some value. For example, `SELECT`ing all rows where `colm` has the JSON string's `level` key-pair value `<= 8`, getting the middle two rows.

How can I do this? I'm thinking something with JSON functions instead of using `LIKE` and `%` wildcards, but I'm not sure exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <your-table> WHERE colm->"$.level" <= 8
```

Comment: Done, was just waiting for the 5 min cooldown before I could mark as answer :P